# Fractional limits exercises

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a test next week on this subject(fractional limits) so it's time to work!

1.$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^3 + x + 1}{x^2 + x + 1} -> {exception case:} \frac{\infty}{\infty} => \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^3(1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^3})}{x^2(1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2})} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x = +\infty$$

2.$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt[3]{x+1} - \sqrt[3]{x}) -> exceptioncase: \infty = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(\sqrt[3]{x+1} - \sqrt[3]{x})(\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2} + \sqrt[3]{x^2})}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2 + \sqrt[3]{x^2})}} =\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2 + \sqrt[3]{x^2})}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\infty} = 0 $$

3.$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2 + \cos x}{x^4 + 1} => exceptioncase: \frac{\infty}{\infty} => \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2(1 + \frac{\cos x}{x^2})}{x^4(1 + \frac{1}{x^4})} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = 0 $$

4.$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2 + \sin x}{-2x^2 + 1} => exceptioncase: \frac{\infty}{-\infty} => \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2(1 + \frac{\sin x}{x^2})}{x^2(-2 + \frac{1}{x^2})} = \frac{1}{-2} $$

5.$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 3}\frac{x^3 - 27}{x^2 - 9} -> {exception case:} \frac{0}{0} => \lim_{x \rightarrow 3}\frac{(x-3)(x^2 + 3x + 9)}{(x-3)(x+3)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 3}\frac{x^2(1 + \frac{3}{x} + \frac{9}{x^2}}{x(1 + \frac{3}{x})} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 3} x = 3$$

How is the verification process for this type of exercies? It's ok to post here exercises?

Thanks!

Comment: if you show us your work,no problem  it is welcome

Comment: I only perused it, but everything seems fine except the last one. You can get rid of $x-3$ both on top and bottom and just replace $x$ in the result expression with $3$ to get $\dfrac {27}6$.

Comment: so common force factor is wrong in the last case?

Comment: @Bacchus Your idea isn't wrong, but it is unnecessary and in the last step you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Git Gud - Yeah, make sense now. Thanks for help!